# Local Storage or similar on Blackberry OS < 6.0

Tags: blackberry, local-storage, opendatabase

I am trying to find a solution for a web app that will be able to operate offline.

I am fine with iOS and Android and Blackberry OS 6.0 and greater as all these support localStorage. I can get certain Blackberrys below OS 0.6 to store information locally with openDatabase but am still failing to find a way to make the following capable of storing data offline-

·         Blackberry Curve 8900

·         Blackberry Curve

·         Blackberry Bold 9700

I do not mind how i end up doing it and am more than happy to use a completely different set up specifically for these BB's.

Essentially all i need to do is store data in any format. I do not mind having to use key - value or a more robust sqllite or simlar. I'm just stumped!

Here's what I have so far to simply detect if the device will accept local storage -

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>  
  <head>
    <title>Local Storage Test</title>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("jquery", "1.4.1");
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function testSupport()
    {
        if (localStorage)
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '<h2 class=\"yes\"><img src=\"http://jealousdesigns.com/webapps/test/tick.png\" /> Yep! This one works (with localStorage)!</h2>';


        if (openDatabase)
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML + '<h2 class=\"yes\"><img src=\"http://jealousdesigns.com/webapps/test/tick.png\" /> Yep! This one works (with database)!</h2>';
    }        

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            font-size: 20px;
            background: #eee;
            color: #666;
        }
        h2{
            border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            background: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px 0;
        }
        .yes{
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
        .no{
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
        <h2 class="no"><img src="http://jealousdesigns.com/webapps/test/x.png" /> Boo. This one doesn't work</h2>
    </div>
    <script>
        testSupport();
    </script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Really all this does is test for localStorage and openDatabase and displays a confirmation message.

I really would appreciate some advice on blackberry devices with an OS of less than 6.0.

Thank you!

Comment: There is a strange situation with some BB's like the 9700 where they cannot save SQLite databases to their built in memory, but the SDCard always works fine, other BB's can save to both. Is that what you are seeing? I'm not sure if this is intentional or not but I once lost the best part of a day to this.

Answer (score 3):

I know that devices less than OS6 do not have native HTML5 support. I also know that From what you've said you have this working on some less than OS6 devices, from that I can deduce that you are using a software layer that is accessing the native API's for you.

You could try swapping this framework for webworks + javascript toolkit.
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Supporting-Gears-using-HTML5-in-BlackBerry-WebWorks-applications/ta-p/557280

I'm assuming this isn't the one you are already using because it doesn't have a localstore api. It does have a database api which should have good cross device support given that it's provided by RIM.

**Why I think this problem is happening on some OS5 phones but not others?**

Only devices with eMMC memory may store SQLite databases on their internal memory.
This excludes the 9700 and I'm guessing the others you mentioned.
So you always have the option to use the SDCard if it's present.

**BB Storage Overview**

This is a link to the storage overview documentation for OS5 and it's the best introduction I've seen:

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/data_storage-summary.html

Options:

- Files and Folders
- SQLite
- Persistent Storage
- Runtime Storage
- MIDP RMS Storage (Record store)

eMMC memory reference = Mark Sohm, BlackBerry Development Advisor
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sqlite-reading-database-from-device-storage-compatibility-list/td-p/764303/highlight/true/page/2

Also an explanation of the types of internal memory is given here:
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/data_storage-summary.html#DS_FileSystem

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful. I will read through those links and get back here to let you know what worked!

Comment: You're welcome, I added another link which is the most useful. RIM's OS5 Data Storage Summary. This includes one other option I missed (Runtime Storage) and example code for each option.

Comment: In fact, if anyone else has this problem I think it's the first document they should read. So I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Hi. I have been through those links and can find no mention of accessing these storage features from a web app. ie manipulation and input of data through javascript. Please correct me if i'm wrong??

I am creating a web app, not a native app.

Comment: Do you use a webapp framework that translates your javascript commands into native ones, if so, which one? Or is it a mobile website?

Comment: Its a mobile website. However I somehow missed your link to the webworks library. That looks promising. If i can get that to work then i will use it as a fallback for devices on which localStorage and openDatabase dont work. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I think you should be able to get it working with OS5 with the webworks tools, my opinion is 4.6-4.7 are not worth supporting as those phones can/should be upgraded to 5. OS4.5 is not very suited for web apps. And below that has too little usage to even consider.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have found two algorithms to add support for older browsers, which defines the property localStorage in the window object, and uses the browser's cache

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage

I'll check it